# JBoss - Could not dereference object

Tags: gwt, jboss, datasource, jndi, connection-pooling

I have created GWT project with jetty and I use JNDI for datasource. When I run GWT app everything works fine, but when I copy .war file to JBoss and I run it, have error.
JBoss version - 4.2.3.GA

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Could not dereference object [Root exception is 
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc not bound] at 
org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.resolveLink(NamingContext.java:1215) at 
org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:758) at 
org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:774) at 
org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:627) at 
javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392) at
```

jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/base</res-ref-name>
        <jndi-name>jdbc/base</jndi-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</jboss-web>
```

jetty-env.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
<New id="base" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
    <Arg>jdbc/base</Arg>
    <Arg>
     <New class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource">
            <Set name="driverClassName">org.postgresql.Driver</Set>
            <Set name="url">jdbc:postgresql://database/test</Set>
            <Set name="username">user</Set>
            <Set name="password">password</Set>
            <Set name="maxActive">10</Set>
            <Set name="maxIdle">4</Set>
     </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
</Configure>
```

web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>My DataSource Reference</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/base</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

GreetingServiceImpl.java

```
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource)ic.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/base");
        Connection con = ds.getConnection();
```

What's wrong? Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved my problem. I created base-ds.xml

```
<datasources>
   <local-tx-datasource>
      <jndi-name>jdbc/base</jndi-name>
      <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://database/test</connection-url>
      <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
      <user-name>user</user-name>
      <password>password</password>
      <min-pool-size>4</min-pool-size>
      <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
   </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

and I changed jndi-name in jboss-web.xml

```
    <jndi-name>java:/jdbc/base</jndi-name>
```

How can I connect Tomcat connection pool for this datasource in JBoss?